# Rails: Inspect an array in template engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am maintaining a 5.2 rails app and I came across the two lines below in the template:

```
<%
clazzes = Clazz.joins(:staffs).includes(clazz_students: :student).where(staffs: { id: @staff.id })  
all_students = clazzes.flat_map { |clazz| clazz.clazz_students.map(&:student) }
%>
```

I have like to somehow inspect `all_students` to see what is in the array.  Something like console log.  Any suggestions on how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`debug`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debug) view helper. Note that you have to change to output mode by changing `<%` to `<%=`.

```
<%=
clazzes = Clazz.joins(:staffs).includes(clazz_students: :student).where(staffs: { id: @staff.id })  
all_students = clazzes.flat_map { |clazz| clazz.clazz_students.map(&:student) }
debug(all_students)
%>
```

Sidenote: Loading and transforming data is usually done in the controller or even in the model when possible. And I would argue that those lines in a view are a code smell and make the view much harder to maintain and potentially to reuse. I suggest moving those lines into the controller method and just calling the instance variables in the view like this:

```
# in the controller method:
@clazzes = Clazz.joins(:staffs).includes(clazz_students: :student).where(staffs: { id: @staff.id })  
@all_students = clazzes.flat_map { |clazz| clazz.clazz_students.map(&:student) }

# in the view
<%= debug(@all_students) %>
```